# Applying the last entry of the same name rows for the whole same named rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have a data set with the rows same name. For example, I would like to do all As in the data (row 0,1,2,3,4) the same price with the last row of A which is 4th row. So all As would be equal to 60. But I would like to this to whole of my data. The same computation for B and C etc. I have lots of data. Is it possible to do this in pandas? I do not want to group them so, I would like to keep all As etc. An example of the data set is below.

```
   Brand      Price    Color      Category

0   A       10         Blue       Shoes
1   A       20         Red        Shoes
2   A       30         Yellow     Shoes 
3   A       40         Pink       Shoes 
4   A       60         Purple     Shoes  
5   B       100        Red        Shoes
6   B       130        Green      Shoes
7   B       150        Blue       Shoes
8   C       170        Yellow     Shoes
9   C       20         Green      Shoes
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried ..? make some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep='last'` for last values per groups:

```
mapping = df.drop_duplicates('Brand', keep='last').set_index('Brand')['Price']
df['Price'] = df['Brand'].map(mapping)
print (df)
  Brand  Price   Color Category
0     A     60    Blue    Shoes
1     A     60     Red    Shoes
2     A     60  Yellow    Shoes
3     A     60    Pink    Shoes
4     A     60  Purple    Shoes
5     B    150     Red    Shoes
6     B    150   Green    Shoes
7     B    150    Blue    Shoes
8     C     20  Yellow    Shoes
9     C     20   Green    Shoes
```

If need define groups by multiple columns (e.g. `Brand` and `Category`) is possible use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df['Price'] = df.groupby(['Brand', 'Category'])['Price'].transform('last')
print (df)
  Brand  Price   Color Category
0     A     60    Blue    Shoes
1     A     60     Red    Shoes
2     A     60  Yellow    Shoes
3     A     60    Pink    Shoes
4     A     60  Purple    Shoes
5     B    150     Red    Shoes
6     B    150   Green    Shoes
7     B    150    Blue    Shoes
8     C     20  Yellow    Shoes
9     C     20   Green    Shoes
```